# Unicode error only when running from another program?

Tags: python, unicode

I have a fun program that displays temperatures. Everything works fine, until I try to use it from Conky:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/naftuli/Documents/i7zdaemon/get-i7z-value", line 85, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/naftuli/Documents/i7zdaemon/get-i7z-value", line 28, in main
    get_temp_value(args)
  File "/home/naftuli/Documents/i7zdaemon/get-i7z-value", line 63, in get_temp_value
    print fmt % (temp if not args.in_fahrenheit else temp * (9.0/5.0) + 32, )
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why is this only throwing an error when used from another program? Everything looks fine when I run it from a terminal directly.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
fmt = u"%d\u00B0C" if not args.in_fahrenheit else u"%d\u00B0F"
# ...
print fmt % (temp if not args.in_fahrenheit else temp * (9.0/5.0) + 32, )
```

That last line kills everything. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you print unicode, the printed text has to be encoded to match whatever encoding is used for the output stream. For Linux terminals, for example, that is usually UTF-8 these days.

But when you use a different program to run your python script, the output stream encoding (a pipe, or a program window other than a terminal), may well use a *different* encoding. In this case, no encoding appears to be set and python then falls back to ASCII. The `\u00B0` character cannot be encoded to ASCII and the encode fails.

Perhaps for this program, printing a lowercase `o` would suffice instead?

Or, the as the [Conky FAQ](http://conky.sourceforge.net/faq.html) seems to suggest, explicitly encode to Latin 1 (ISO 8859-1) to output the degree symbol:

```
print (fmt % (temp if not args.in_fahrenheit else temp * (9.0/5.0) + 32, )).encode('latin1')
```

And [this posting](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=765995) seems to hint that encoding to UTF-8 is also an option (depending on Conky configuration)? Replace `latin1` in the above example with `utf8` to try that encoding instead.

Also see the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), which specifies how output encoding is handled.

Comment: What I did was set `override_utf8_locale yes` in my Conky config, and then I modified my script to have a new `--output-encoding` parameter which defaults to `utf8`. Worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the coding in the top of your src file like this:

```
# coding: UTF-8
```

Comment: This won't magically fix *output* encoding, this only applies to how python *reads* the *source code*.